# When linking with undefined version of a libary is a correct choice?

Tags: dynamic-linking

With `strace` I see that a program needs some unspecified version of `gmp` library:

```
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = \
   -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I think it should be linked with a particular interface version (e.g. `libgmp.so.10` for example).

This does not look like common practice though. Is this by accident or is there a valid reason to rely on unspecified version?

The only acceptable case I can think of is OS distribution: you build (and control) every package.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't say "unacceptable", but it is definitely unusual for a binary to search for a shared library under the plain `*.so` name at runtime. Usually:

- The (build-time) linker searches for libraries under names matching `*.so`
- If found, the linker consults the SONAME field of the library to find out the name the library should be located as at runtime
- It records that name inside the built binary so that becomes what it searches for at run time.

The purpose of this convention is so that the binary can be tied to a specific API-version of the library.

Perhaps the library in question is not using this convention. To check, see if the library contains an SONAME field:

```
objdump -p /lib/`arch`-linux-gnu/libthing.so | fgrep SONAME
```

If no SONAME exists, then binaries linked against that library will default to using the name under which the library was found at build time (which is `*.so`). That might be what you're seeing. If a SONAME exists, then binaries linking against that library should have been using that name at run time.